# pandas transform dataframe and compute datetimedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas datetime like this:

```
col1   col2        col3   col4
aa     30-11-2017  ba     01-11-2017
aa     30-11-2017  bb     10-11-2017
ab     25-11-2017  bc     20-11-2017
ac     01-12-2017  bc     30-11-2017
```

My expected output is:

```
col1   ba   bb   bc
aa     29   20   0
ab     0    0    5
ac     0    0    1
```

The logic is:
For each unique value in `col1`, compute the date difference (in days) between `col2` and `col4`, then assign it to the right column based on the unique value in `col3`

My initial approach to this is a combination of `pd.groupby()` and `pd.assign()`
But can't seem to work it out. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col3']).apply(lambda x: (x['col2'] - x['col4']).iloc[0] / pd.Timedelta('1d')).unstack().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
col3    ba    bb   bc
col1                 
aa    29.0  20.0  0.0
ab     0.0   0.0  5.0
ac     0.0   0.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
In [1299]: (df.col2.sub(df.col4).dt.days
              .groupby([df.col1, df.col3]).first()
              .unstack(fill_value=0))
Out[1299]:
col3  ba  bb  bc
col1
aa    29  20   0
ab     0   0   5
ac     0   0   1
```